# Bad pulley or Belt?

Tags: oil-leak, smoke, belt, pulley

Okay so I had my car break down about a week ago and from looking at the car myself and using my common sense, after Turing the car on for about 8 seconds all I heard was squealing and smoke coming from the belt, I know it’s from the belt because after touching everything after those 8 seconds the belt was the only thing that was able to burn me, what would you guys recommend me do at this point to further investigate or help me narrow down the problem. Also not sure if it had to do with whatever is burning the belt but after the break down a decent amount of oil from a what looks like a bolt on the side of the engine and also around the injectors. Let me know what you would do thank you!!  https://ibb.co/cDNQFLS https://ibb.co/WfXr7g1

Comment: Has the idler or a/c pulley seized?

Comment: My first check would be to make sure all the pulleys are turning as @SolarMike says.

Comment: The oil seems to be unrelated to the main issue here, I would first check the belt tension, to make sure it has the correct amount of slack, if it does, I would remove the belt and check all the pulleys if they turn freely as the guys above suggested. At any rate, if the belt tensioner was lose it wouldn't produce smoke and that much heat, they usually squik for a while and that's all.

Comment: So I took a deeper look and moved some things out the way to look at the belt and the pulleys, I was easily able to get the belt off till it was the alternators turn, the belt was melted onto the alternator, and the pulley was the one that couldn’t spin almost at all took a lot of force, am I able to change the pulley or do you guys think I’m going to have to change the alternator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, it looks like the alternator has seized.

> I was easily able to get the belt off till it was the alternators
>   turn, the belt was melted onto the alternator, and the pulley was the
>   one that couldn’t spin

Unfortunately you will need to either get the alternator reconditioned or get a new one fitted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the belt off, noting every pulley it turns (aside from the crank pulley).
2. Try to turn every pulley you noted in step 1 (including the tensionor).
3. Any device with a pulley you cannot turn by hand, should be inspected.

Many air conditioner compressors have a clutch that takes the load off the engine when not in use.  So with the A/C off (like when the engine is not running), there will be very little resistance.  When you ran the engine for 8 seconds, was the A/C on?

Many shops can test your alternator, and some will do so for free.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the alternator, I would suspect the rotor has been in contact with the stator and it is well-past reconditioning.

Well, if you have access to new stator, new rotor and new bearings it is possible, but at that point a replacement unit that comes with a guarantee is a better option.